# No Quick edit avilable for current cursor position in Brackets

Tags: brackets, adobe-brackets, emmet, zen

In My **Brackets IDE**, I install **Emnet**   But When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> for anything, it just shows **No Quick edit available for current cursor position**.

Answer (score 0):

Just use <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or you can also follow on  [GitHub Repo](http://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet/blob/master/keymap.json)